# חצי לה׳, חצי לך

Tags: halacha, shabbat

If all Torah learning is for ourselves, and, when we do Hashem’s will, our will becomes His will, then how can we say YomTov  is: חצי לה׳, חצי לכם (See [Beitzah 15b](https://www.sefaria.org/Beitzah.15b.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)), it’s either כולם לה׳ or כולם לכם, but still have the same Halachos?

Comment: Where does it say חצי לה׳, חצי לך? What does it mean and where does it say "all Torah learning is for ourselves" and "when we do Hashem’s will, our will becomes his will" (I think that will explain your problem of "it’s either כולם לה׳ or כולם לך" but if not please explain your logic for that too). Why are you equating Shabbat to Torah learning? What does "but still have the same Halachos?" mean and how did you arrive at it?

Comment: @RabbiKaii  Ok, first, it’s in ביצה דף ט״ו, second it’s talking about YomTov, third “same Halachos“, meaning learning half the day, and half the day enjoying the גוף. I can’t remember where it says all Torah learning is for ourselves, but it’s obvious if the world was made for us, and we were made to learn Torah. I also can’t remember where it says when we do Hashem’s will it becomes our will, but I remember my רב saying so.

Comment: Related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/121313/source-for-vilna-gaons-gematriah-about-%d7%97%d7%a6%d7%99-%d7%9c%d7%94-and-%d7%97%d7%a6%d7%99-%d7%9c%d7%9b%d7%9d (just need to find the Vilna Gaon!!)

Comment: @hayam it's a good question, edit the answer with those details if poss

Comment: [Edit](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/141190/edit) the question*

Comment: @hayam "_I can’t remember where it says all Torah learning is for ourselves, but it’s obvious if the world was made for us, and we were made to learn Torah._" If we were made to to learn Torah, then it is our obligation, to our Maker, and we do it for Him, not for us. If the world was made for us, then enjoying it (in eating and drinking) is for us. Where does Torah learning being for ourselves come into this?